# Set background color of several cells at once

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a value and background for selected cells.

Setting value works, setting color does not work.

```vb
Function InRange(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range) As Boolean
    Dim InterSectRange As Range
    Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(Range1, Range2)
    InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
    Set InterSectRange = Nothing
End Function

Sub test()
    If InRange(ActiveCell, Range("A1:AA40")) Then
        Set selectedRange = Application.Selection        
        selectedRange.Value = "That Works!"
        selectedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 1
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: This should work. However, no reason to loop, you can assign the values and the color at once with `selectedRange.value = "It works"`  and `selectedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 1`

Comment: Btw `.ColorIndex` is an index into the current color palette, not an absolute color.

Comment: @FunThomas: That doesn't work without loop. Value setting works, not color setting.

Comment: Believe me, it works. I usually don't post without testing first.

Comment: If you want a specific color, you really really really should be using `.Interior.Color`. Also no repro, your code works. What specifically happens or doesn't happen on your end?

Comment: @FunThomas: Ok, you are right. setting background color was blocked by default on this sheet. On another sheet, that worked. Is there any option to set bgcolor via vba even it's blocked?

Comment: Only by unprotecting (which can be done programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

The use of `InRange()` should be your issue.  That isn't a native function for Excel-VBA; it would be custom, and as such throws an error.

You can use `Intersect()` for native Excel-VBA, e.g.:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A1:AA40")) Is Nothing Then
```

Additional point, try to make use of `Option explicit` at the top of your module, enforcing that all variables are dimensioned.